# ToggleClass not working properly

Tags: jquery, css

Why does my toggleclass not work?

http://jsfiddle.net/xH8ME/1/

(The `toggleclass()` doesnt work, but it should work)

Comment: from what I can see it is toggling the class `warnings_receiver_highlight` it is just having those styles overridden by your `userGridViewItem` class.

Comment: Hence the "cascade" in CSS :) last wins, resequence the style sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working but the styles are getting overriden.

Try with this:

```
.warnings_receiver_highlight {
    background: #000 !important;
    color: #000  !important;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xH8ME/3/

Comment: The "weight" of the style selector is raised by the !important.  Of note, this could also be resolved by the "sequence" which would weigh a latter definition higher - so resequence to have the highlight style LAST would also work.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you want, all you should have to do is place the styles in your css for `warnings_receiver_highlight` after your styles for `userGridViewItem`.

Answer (score 0):

The toggle class is working fine it is your CSS that is messed up I have a corrected fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/xH8ME/2/

Basically you have the two classes defined below. Since your divs have both classes how does the browser know which background should be applied?  Because .userGridViewItem is defined first in the element that is the class that it pulls the background color from.  To make this work properly you need to use the `!important` at the end of the attribute or make your CSS classes more specific like `div.warnings_receiver_highlight`  or `.userGridViewItem.warnings_receiver_highlight`

```
.warnings_receiver_highlight{
    background: #000;
    color: #000;
}
.userGridViewItem{
    background: brown;
    color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is working correctly, you just seem to be having an issue with CSS specificity (http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). One solution would be to add `!important` to the attributes under `.warnings_receiver_highlight`

Answer (score 0):

Place the desired override last.  Also, you can apply !important to the style but to ensure that if another is given !important, the sequence will still weigh higher.  Your fiddle page also had an extra `}` at the end.

```
.userGridViewItem{
    background: brown;
    color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
.warningYellow{
    border: 3px solid yellow;
}
.warnings_receiver_highlight{
    background: #000 !important;
    color: #000 !important;
}
```